# How to create multiple directories with sub directories from text file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, subdirectory

```
#!/bin/bash
prev='placeholder'
filename='mkDir.txt'
echo "Starting mkDir script using mkDir.txt."
while IFS=' ' read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "creating dir : $line"
    if [[ ${line:0:1} == [[:space:]] ]]
    then
        cd $prev
        mkdir $line
        cd '..'
    else
        mkdir $line
    fi
    prev=$line
done < $filename
```

This is my current script. It doesn’t however create the subdirectories as I want it to. My ideal text file will look like this :

```
tester
    test
test2
```

The tabs/spaces are supposed to indicate that this is a subdirectory. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please update the question with what is problem with your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would rather use an AWK program to generate a bash script from the input file and then run the bash script:

```
#!/bin/awk
# WARNING: this example assumes there are is no whitespace in the directory names!
BEGIN { parentdir = "." }
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { next }
/^[[:space:]]/ { print "mkdir " parentdir "/" $1; next }
{ parentdir = $1; print "mkdir " parentdir }
```

AWK is called like this: awk -f file-with-code-from-above mkDir.txt

A file mkDir.txt with content

```
 subdir
dir1
 subdir
dir2
 subdir
```

would produce the output

```
mkdir ./subdir
mkdir dir1
mkdir dir1/subdir
mkdir dir2
mkdir dir2/subdir
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using [Bash arrays](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)**

```
#!/bin/bash -

function join { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

branch=()
while IFS=/ read -r -a parts; do
    level=${#parts[@]}
    branch=( ${branch[@]:0:$level} )

    (( --level ))

    branch[$level]="${parts[$level]}"

    mkdir -p $(join / "${branch[@]}")
done < <(sed -e 's~\t~/~g' input.txt)
```

- `join` function joins `$2 .. $*` arguments using `$1` separator
- `sed` command replaces tabs with slashes from `input.txt` file
- the output of the `sed` command is redirected to `while` loop by means of [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)
- `IFS` is the [field separator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)
- `${branch[@]:0:$level}` extracts `branch` array items from `0` to `$level - 1` inclusively

**In PHP**

```php
<?php
$branch = [];
$fp = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
  $parts = explode("\t", $line);
  $level = count($parts);
  $branch = array_slice($branch, 0, $level);
  $branch[$level - 1] = trim($parts[$level - 1]);

  mkdir(implode('/', $branch), 0755, true);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Usage:

```
php script.php < input.txt
```